tonkeeper ton tutorial wallet address mismatch
I am going through the tutorial in the hello world series and am facing an issue where the wallet address and balance being printed is not of the wallet from tonkeeper even though I am using the same mnemonic. Here is the code from step7.ts from the tutorial. Any help is greatly appreciated.
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';
    import { WalletContractV4 } from '@ton/ton';
    import { mnemonicToWalletKey } from '@ton/crypto';

    dotenv.config();

    async function main() {
      // open wallet v4 (notice the correct wallet version here)
      const mnemonic = process.env.MNEMONIC1 || '';
      const key = await mnemonicToWalletKey(mnemonic.split(' '));
      const wallet = WalletContractV4.create({
        publicKey: key.publicKey,
        workchain: 0,
      });

      console.log(wallet);
      // print wallet address
      console.log(wallet.address.toString({ testOnly: true }));

      // print wallet workchain
      console.log('workchain:', wallet.address.workChain);
    }

main();


Do you get the issue of why its different? I am facing the same problem
